# ESLint dependency (strip-json-comments) not being found when trying Webpack build

Tags: webpack, eslint

I have installed the latest webpack and eslint packages in order to start using the eslint-loader, etc.  After installing everything and getting my config files in place I started getting this error when trying to run a webpack build:

```
Error: stripComments is not a function
```

I found that this method is used inside of an eslint file and when looking at the ESLint npm package page I can see that there is supposed to be a dependency on the `strip-json-comments` package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint (Go to Dependencies and you will see that dep)

However, after a fresh installation of `eslint` in my project, I don't see this as a dependency in my `package-lock.json` file:

```
"eslint": {
      "version": "4.19.1",
      "resolved": "https://www.myget.org/F/legacy/npm/eslint/-/eslint-4.19.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-MtHWU+HZBAiFS/spbwdux+GGowA=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ajv": "5.5.2",
        "babel-code-frame": "6.26.0",
        "chalk": "2.4.1",
        "concat-stream": "1.6.2",
        "cross-spawn": "5.1.0",
        "debug": "3.1.0",
        "doctrine": "2.1.0",
        "eslint-scope": "3.7.3",
        "eslint-visitor-keys": "1.0.0",
        "espree": "3.5.4",
        "esquery": "1.0.1",
        "esutils": "2.0.2",
        "file-entry-cache": "2.0.0",
        "functional-red-black-tree": "1.0.1",
        "glob": "7.1.2",
        "globals": "11.7.0",
        "ignore": "3.3.10",
        "imurmurhash": "0.1.4",
        "inquirer": "3.3.0",
        "is-resolvable": "1.1.0",
        "js-yaml": "3.12.0",
        "json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify": "1.0.1",
        "levn": "0.3.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.10",
        "minimatch": "3.0.4",
        "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
        "natural-compare": "1.4.0",
        "optionator": "0.8.2",
        "path-is-inside": "1.0.2",
        "pluralize": "7.0.0",
        "progress": "2.0.0",
        "regexpp": "1.1.0",
        "require-uncached": "1.0.3",
        "semver": "5.5.0",
        "strip-ansi": "4.0.0",
        // IT SHOULD BE RIGHT HERE! :(
        "table": "4.0.2",
        "text-table": "0.2.0"
      }
```

All of the other dependencies on the npm website (see link above) are in this list except for `strip-json-comments` which would totally explain why its not being found at runtime.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I tried googling this issue thinking it was a bug on their side but I don't see many other people talking about this so I feel like it is somehow affecting only me.  There is another package I found that also uses this as a dependency and it is actually in the `package-lock.json` as I would expect. That package is called `rc`. Not sure what it is for exactly but that is the only reference to `strip-json-comments` I could find.

**UPDATE**

I found that the type being exported by `strip-json-comments` is an `EventEmitter` which would totally explain why it can't just be used like a function. There must be some sort of conflict going on because webpack wants to use this thing as a function when it is clearly not a function:

The main file for this package is set to `./lib/npm.js` and if I look into that file I see this:

```
var npm = module.exports = new EventEmitter()
```

Which is clearly not a function... what is going on :(

**UPDATE 2**

Ok after some more digging I can see that the version of `strip-json-comments` that I am having installed when running `npm install eslint` is actually **INSTALLING NPM THE PACKAGE ITSELF**... I can see the authors of this file and its literally the entire `npm` team. WTF... idk what is happening but I think it might have to do with my private repository feed on MyGet.org...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that the issue was with MyGet.org itself... I have a private feed up there that I then have npmjs.org mirrored to. For some absolutely insane reason, the `strip-json-comments` package in my private feed was corrupted somehow and the actual package it was resolving to on the npmjs.org side was `npm` itself. Like the actual package you download when you install `npm` was being used in place of this little comment stripping package.  I have absolutely no idea how this happened but I just created a new feed and re-mirrored the packages and now everything works fine...